# How to run NodeJS+MongoDB project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, yaml

I have experience of run node.js project. 
It contains package.json and I use npm install command. and run node app.js after installation.
Please see this project: https://github.com/krutt/Wild-Ones
It's node.js project. But I can't install this. It has no package.json file.
How can I deploy this server on my computer?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, there's no package.json, so it's not a ready-to-deploy project.  You would need to clone/fork the repo, do npm init, add dependencies, debug, etc.  Lots of stuff that can't be covered in a single answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have one more question. 
In this project, you can see _config.yml.  Will you explain about it please?

Comment: the contents of that file is a "theme", which implies it's a configuration for some kind of UI framework.  Not sure which one...